# online-experiment: how add ms wait into item with html/js?

Tags: javascript, audio, wait

I have an online experiment made with javascript and some html on Ibexfarms. My items look like this: audio prime, then word on screen (participants need to press key).
I need a 200ms wait between the end of the audio file and the word display. 
How do I add this?

```
[
  ["1",1], 
  "AudioMessage", 
  {
    html: "..." <audio class='audio-message' source src='http...mp3'  type='audio/mp3' autoplay></audio>", 
    transfer: "audio-end"
  }, 
  "Question", 
  {
    q: "freudig", hasCorrect:0
  }
],
```

The syntax doesn't allow to add `transfer: 200` anywhere between "audio-end" and q. 
Placed directly after `transfer: "audio-end"`, it overrides it and the files aren't played.

I also can't replace `transfer: "audio-end"` by `transfer: 200` as this will lead to the audios not being played at all.

The obvious answer would be to just add `transfer: 200` to the controllers "Question" or "AudioMessage", but that doesn't have any effect:

```
"Question", {
        as: [["Answer1, answer2"]], //irrelevant  
        (...)
        transfer: 200 
    },
```

I also can't add something like `function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 2000);` into the item line (top), it won't allow it...

Does anyone an answer to quite a simple problem (I think)?
Help greatly appreciated!